# Публикация дополнения для Гугл-таблиц

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet, google-services

Я написал небольшой скрипт в Google Apps Script и хочу опубликовать его как дополнение для таблиц гугл, но после публикации он просто не качается из-за ошибки. И все дело в манифесте, вопрос такой: "Каким должен выглядеть манифест и что должно быть в коде манифеста?" и если можно, поделитесь пожалуйста ссылкой на то что и зачем должно быть в манифесте, если такое существует.

Comment: Никаким. Система сама создает манифест. Вам ничего качать, вкачивать, вычачивать и перекачивать не нужно. Чаще всего.

Comment: Спасибо большое!